# Unable to convert output to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer

How to create a function that takes a list of non-negative integers and strings and return a new list without the strings?

Eg. `filter_list([1, 2, "a", "b"])` ➞ `[1, 2]`

Issue: Not able to convert output to list

```
def filter_list(a):
    mylist=[]
    if type(a)==list:
        for i in a:
            if type(i)==int:
                output=print(i)
        mylist+=output
        return mylist
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing `output = print(i)` which means, you are assigning `None` to `output` since `print` returns `None`. You should just print i, and then write `mylist += [i]`

Comment: @SanjeevanKhanduri..I tried  print(i) and after that mylist+=i...It is not giving nonetype error now but also not converting the output to list..What mistake did I do?

Comment: @ANURAGVERMA `i` is an integer and `mylist` is a list, you can't add a list and an integer using `+` operator. You will have to convert `i` to a list first. And you can do that by adding square brackets around it, `[i]`. and then you can add, `mylist += [i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you made is that you are assigning the value returned by `print()` to `output` (which is `None`) and then you are adding a `None` type object to a `list` object which is an invalid operation. You can fix your code by doing something like this :

```
def filter_list(a):
    mylist=[]
    if type(a)==list:
        for i in a:
            if type(i)==int:
                print(i)
                mylist+=[i]
        return mylist
```

However this can be done in a much prettier way using List comprehensions! 
List comprehension is a way to create a new list using a relatively much shorter syntax.

```
[elem for elem in _list if type(elem) is int]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension which only includes list elements if they have the `int` type.

```
def filter_list(lis):
    return [i for i in lis if type(i) == int]

print(filter_list([1, 2, "a", "b"]))
```

Code Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can this help:

```py
>>> def filter_list(lst):
    return [item for item in lst if type(item) is not str]

>>> filter_list([1, 2, 'a', 'b'])
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def filter_list(lst):
    return [i for i in lst if isinstance(i, int)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `filter` function itself:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), [1, 2, "a", "b"]))
[1, 2]
```

Issue with your code is that instead of printing and using `+=` (which is used to concatenate two lists, not one `list` and one `int`) to add to your list, you should append the element like this:

```
for i in a:
    if type(i) == int:
        mylist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method as follows:

```
def filter_list(a):
    return list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, a))

print(filter_list([1, 2, "a", "b"]))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2]
```

**Your code fixed:**

```
def filter_list(a):
    mylist=[]
    for i in a:
        if type(i)==int:
            mylist.append(i)
    return mylist

def filter_list1(a):
    return list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, a))

print(filter_list([1, 2, "a", "b"]), filter_list1([1, 2, "a", "b"]))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2] [1, 2]
```